# How to Solve Check Component Dependency Error during Magento Upgrade?

Tags: magento2.2, magento-upgrade, web-setup-wizard, magento2.2.7

I want to update magento-2.1.12 to magento-2.2.7 using Web Setup Wizard.

We faced this error Check Component Dependency(We found conflicting component dependencies.).

How to solve this error? Please guide me.

This is [Screenshot of Error](https://paste.pics/4FXG5)

Comment: screenshot not working

Comment: question updated please check screenshot again @magefms .

Comment: if you have a custom module (that might be of a custom module), try to remove that first and check if error disappear then  proceed with upgrade, after upgrade install your custom module again.

Comment: We have many custom modules . So, Can we remove all modules? @magefms

Comment: yeah since you are not sure which custom module has dependencies that causes the conflict. After upgrade, you can reinstall all the custom modules without any issues

Comment: ok i will try...

Comment: I will deleted all custom module,app/code is empty.Now i will check upgrade again,But still it showing same error. @magefms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87745/discussion-between-magefms-and-lovely-setia).